# Pure death poisson process

Tags: markov-process, poisson-distribution

I have a pure death process $X=\{X(t) : 0 \leq t < \infty\}$ with parameters $\lambda_n=0$ and $\mu_n=\mu$ and if $X(0)=N$ and I'm supposed to determine $P_n(t)=P\{X(t)=n\}$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots,N$

So I'm supposed to find $\Pr(X(t)=n\mid X(0)=N)$.  I beleive this is a Poisson process to find the probability that exactly $N-n$ deaths have happened by time $t$, is that correct?  How would I express this probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_t$ be a Poisson process with rate $\mu$.  Since $\mu_n = \mu$, we can take the deaths as following $Y_t$ until everyone has died.  So given you start with $N$ people, and $n \ge 0$, the probability that $X(t) = n$ is the probability that there are exactly $N-n$ occurrences in the $Y_t$ process in the interval $[0,t]$.  The number of such occurrences in an interval of length $t$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter ..., so its probability of taking the value $N-n$ is ....

Comment: Would it be (N choose n) $(e^{-\alpha t})^n [1-e^{-\alpha t}]^{N-n}$?

Comment: Is that the probability mass function of a Poisson random variable at $N-n$?

Comment: Ahh, no it would be $\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{N-n}}{(N-n)!}$, except since it is a pure death process, I would replace $\lambda$ with $\mu$ to get $\frac{e^{-\mu} \mu^{N-n}}{(N-n)!}$

Comment: Is that correct? or am I still wrong here?

Comment: Not quite right.  The parameter of the Poisson random variable is $\mu t$, not $\mu$.

Comment: ok so $Pr(X(t)=n|X(0)=N)=\frac{e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{N-n}}{(N-n)!}$?  I appreciate your help